# Variance of "an observation" and problem 5.9.8 in BDA by Gelman, et. al

Tags: self-study, bayesian, mixture-distribution

I would like to understand problem 5.9.8 in Bayesian Data Analysis by Gelman, *et al.*. In particular the problem asks:

> ... create a bimodal prior density for a normal mean, that is thought to be near  $1$, with a standard deviation of $0.5$, but has a small probability of being near $−1$, with the same standard deviation. If the variance of each observation  $y_1,...,y_{10}$ is known to be $1$, and their observed mean is  $y=−0.25$, derive your posterior distribution for the mean, making a sketch of both prior and posterior densities.

**What does "the variance of each observation ... is known to be $1$" mean?**

More specifically, the solution to this problem requires computing $P(y_1,..., y_{10})$ for each of these two normal distributions given the knowledge that $\overline{y}=-0.25$. My instinct was to do this using the $t$-distribution, interpreting the "variance" statement as "the sample variance." But that does not seem to be consistent with the solutions available on the web:

http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/solutions2.pdf

In which they state that $P(y)=F(-0.25,\; \pm 1,\; 0.5^2+1/10)$ where $F$ is the
normal probability distribution with mean $\pm 1$ (in the two cases) and variance $0.5^2+1/10$.

Comment: "Of each observation" suggests that this should be interpreted as the true variance, since sample variance cannot be calculated using a single data point. Also, I do not see exercise 5.9.8 in the linked doc.